# Silverlight: Select control based on list count

Tags: silverlight, xaml, telerik

I'm bind a Telerik RadGridView to a `List<MyObject> myList = new List<MyObject>`. But if the `myList.Count == 0` (the list is empty ;) ) I want to show another control to the user.

I know I could use some visibility converter, but I prefer achieving this in XAML.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that value converters are your only choice here :)
However, I've found out that if you structure them properly, value converters are great.

Here are a couple of good tools for this:

- [A Generic Boolean Value Converter](http://geekswithblogs.net/codingbloke/archive/2010/05/28/a-generic-boolean-value-converter.aspx)
- [Linking Multiple Value Converters in WPF and Silverlight](http://www.garethevans.com/2010/07/linking-multiple-value-converters-in-wpf-and-silverlight/)

With these tools in mind, I would go with something like this:

```
    <Grid>
        <telerik:RadGridView ItemsSource="{Binding myList}">
            <telerik:RadGridView.Visibility>
                <Binding Path="myList">
                    <Binding.Converter>
                        <converters:SequentialValueConverter>
                            <converters:IsEmptyConverter />
                            <converters:BooleanToVisibilityConverter TrueValue="Collapsed" FalseValue="Visible" />
                        </converters:SequentialValueConverter>
                    </Binding.Converter>
                </Binding>
            </telerik:RadGridView.Visibility>
        </telerik:RadGridView>
        <YourControl>
            <YourControl.Visibility>
                <Binding Path="myList">
                    <Binding.Converter>
                        <converters:SequentialValueConverter>
                            <converters:IsEmptyConverter />
                            <converters:BooleanToVisibilityConverter TrueValue="Visible" FalseValue="Collapsed" />
                        </converters:SequentialValueConverter>
                    </Binding.Converter>
                </Binding>
            </YourControl.Visibility>
        </YourControl>
    </Grid>
```

Also, as Jason said, myList needs to be an ObservableCollection so the gui gets notified when it changes.

Hope it helps!

Comment: In fact, I'm using a CollectionViewSource where the source is myList. Work great in my application context. So I guess I will be implementing thoses converter.

Answer (score 0):

If you switched to `ObservableCollection<MyObject>` you can bind using VisibilityConverters to that your `myList.Count` all in XAML.  If you are having issues because you are setting the ItemsSource in codebehind, you may want to have it be a resource or switch to something more MVVM.

Comment: I'm using MVVM, no code behind. I want to switch control when myList is empty, for a better interaction with the user.